# Have search function need help editing

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a code I have written the first part of the code is to create a new worksheet with the headings specified. The second part of the code is meant to populate that table with certain information. The problem I am having is getting the correct bits of information to go into the correct columns.
 I need the code to search for the value 9.1 in column G in all worksheets within a workbook
 if that value is found I need it to copy this to column b in the new sheet along with the following information :

Engine Effect from Column F Same row must be pasted to Column C in the worksheet entitled FHA
 Part number is always located in Cell J3 this must be pasted into column D and is always the same
 Part Name Is Always located in C2 this must be pasted into column E and is always the same
 FM ID from Column B same row must be pasted to Column F in the worksheet entitled FHA
 Failure Mode & Cause from Column C Same row must be pasted to column G in FHA
 FMCN Value From Column N pasted to Column H In FHA

As It stands the code I have is

```
Sub createWSheetFHA()
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "FHA"

    Cells(1, 2) = "FHA TABLE"
    Cells(2, 2) = "FHA Ref"
    Cells(2, 3) = "Engine Effect"
    Cells(2, 4) = "Part No"
    Cells(2, 5) = "Part Name"
    Cells(2, 6) = "FM I.D"
    Cells(2, 7) = "Failure Mode & Cause"
    Cells(2, 8) = "FMCM"
    Cells(2, 9) = "PTR"
    Cells(2, 10) = "ETR"

    Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, 10)).Font.Bold = True
    Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, 10)).MergeCells = True
    Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, 10)).Font.Bold = True

End Sub
Sub Populate_FHA_Table_2()
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet, i As Integer, n As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("FHA").Range("A2:" & Columns.Count & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
    i = 1
    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wks.Name <> "FHA" Then
            wks.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="9.1"
            Sheets(i).Range(Sheets(i).Range("G1").Offset(1), Sheets(i).Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Copy _
                Sheets("FHA").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            Sheets(i).Range(Sheets(i).Range("F1").Offset(1), Sheets(i).Range("D1").End(xlDown)).Copy _
                Sheets("FHA").Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            Sheets(i).Range(Sheets(i).Range("J1").Offset(1), Sheets(i).Range("E1").End(xlDown)).Copy _
                Sheets("FHA").Range("e" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            Sheets(i).Range(Sheets(i).Range("C1").Offset(1), Sheets(i).Range("H1").End(xlDown)).Copy _
                Sheets("FHA").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            Sheets(i).Range(Sheets(i).Range("B1").Offset(1), Sheets(i).Range("H1").End(xlDown)).Copy _
                Sheets("FHA").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            Sheets(i).Range(Sheets(i).Range("C1").Offset(1), Sheets(i).Range("H1").End(xlDown)).Copy _
                Sheets("FHA").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            Sheets(i).Range(Sheets(i).Range("N1").Offset(1), Sheets(i).Range("H1").End(xlDown)).Copy _
                Sheets("FHA").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            wks.UsedRange.AutoFilter
        End If
    i = i + 1
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mismatches in your code (Example using 'for each wk' then accessing via an index 'i'; where they may not necessarily match)

Try something like this...

I have added in some dynamic flow control which isn't strictly needed but if and when your headers change in the future, it may be easier to have it in this form.

Likewise I have tried to add in some error handling as well

```
Sub Create_FHA_Sheet()
    Dim Headers() As String: Headers = _
    Split("FHA Ref,Engine Effect,Part No,Part Name,FM I.D,Failure Mode & Cause,FMCM,PTR,ETR", ",")

    If Not WorksheetExists("FHA") Then Worksheets.Add().Name = "FHA"
    Dim wsFHA As Worksheet: Set wsFHA = Sheets("FHA")
    wsFHA.Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    wsFHA.Cells.Clear

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With wsFHA
        For i = 0 To UBound(Headers)
            .Cells(2, i + 2) = Headers(i)
            .Columns(i + 2).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Next i
        .Cells(1, 2) = "FHA TABLE"
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, UBound(Headers) + 2)).MergeCells = True
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, UBound(Headers) + 2)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(2, UBound(Headers) + 2)).Font.Bold = True
    End With

    Dim RowCounter As Long: RowCounter = 3
    Dim SearchTarget As String: SearchTarget = "9.1"
    Dim SourceCell As Range, FirstAdr As String

    If Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
        For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1
        With Sheets(i)
            Set SourceCell = .Columns(7).Find(SearchTarget, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not SourceCell Is Nothing Then
                FirstAdr = SourceCell.Address
                Do
                    wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 3).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 6).Value
                    wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 4).Value = .Cells(3, 10).Value
                    wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 5).Value = .Cells(2, 3).Value
                    wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 6).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 2).Value
                    wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 7).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 3).Value
                    wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 8).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 14).Value
                    Set SourceCell = .Columns(7).FindNext(SourceCell)
                    RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
                Loop While Not SourceCell Is Nothing And SourceCell.Address <> FirstAdr
            End If
        End With
        Next i
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function WorksheetExists(ByVal WorksheetName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WorksheetExists = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WorksheetName).Name <> "")
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: that solution is perfect. Just a question on if it is possible to get it to search for multiple code values. In addition to that I just found out that if the value for failure mode and cause is 'continued' then I need to take the value from the cell above. this would have to loop until a value that is not 'continued' is found

Comment: You could search for multiple code values by looping the main process code and alter 'SearchTarget' each time. This is why it is external to the main loop to allow the extensibility.
For the further functionality you would need to add a check loop which sees if the value is 'continued' and if it is then loop through 'SourceCell.Row - i' where i is incrementing until the value is not continued or i = SourceCell.Row

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. I only started using vba last week but every time I try a loop code it seems to cause excel to not respond. (Im assuming because I have probably set up an infinite loop or something)

Comment: Well - if you can accept this answer (as it works and is related to the original question) then start another question with the additional changes you want detailed - then I can have a look at it later. (post a link to the new question here)

Comment: Not a problem thanks very much for your help on this issue. you have moved my project on leaps and bounds. this post is just for the looping portion of the code but im willing to figure the rest out on my own after that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891314/loop-up-rows-until-value-does-not-equal-continued

Comment: Add further detail to the other question; you'll get marked down for lack of detail otherwise...
Also, you need to give context i.e. larger portions of the code

Comment: thanks for the tip. not really sure if ive made myself clear enough yet. struggling to phrase my request coherently.