# Loop Up rows until Value DOES NOT equal Continued

Tags: excel, vba

This is a small section of a larger code. basically if the cell contains the word continued I need to look in the cell above, if this cell contains the word continued then I need to continue to loop up the rows until a value which is not continued is found. This is what I have so far ?

```
      Do
            If .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 3).Value = "continued." Then
              wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 7).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Offset(rowoffset:=-1).Row, 3).Value

            End If
      Loop Until .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 3).Value <> "continued."
```

The code above is a smaller part of this code the code is to search for failure mode and causes. However in the source data sometimes the same value is repeated. in this case the word continued appears in the cell and you must refer to the information in the cell above. However for the purposes of coalating the data i need the actual information not the word continued. im trying to make the code find this information but am struggling.

```
Sub Create_FHA_Table()
    Dim Headers() As String: Headers = _
    Split("FHA Ref,Engine Effect,Part No,Part Name,FM I.D,Failure Mode & Cause,FMCM,PTR,ETR", ",")

    If Not WorksheetExists("FHA") Then Worksheets.Add().Name = "FHA"
    Dim wsFHA As Worksheet: Set wsFHA = Sheets("FHA")
    wsFHA.Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    wsFHA.Cells.Clear

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With wsFHA
        For i = 0 To UBound(Headers)
            .Cells(2, i + 2) = Headers(i)
            .Columns(i + 2).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Next i
        .Cells(1, 2) = "FHA TABLE"
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, UBound(Headers) + 2)).MergeCells = True
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, UBound(Headers) + 2)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(2, UBound(Headers) + 2)).Font.Bold = True
    End With



    Dim RowCounter As Long: RowCounter = 3
    Dim SearchTarget As String 'must copy and paste between these bookmarks for each new code, "SearchTarget#"
    SearchTarget = "9.1" 'Must update SearchTarget#
    Dim SourceCell As Range, FirstAdr As String

    If Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
        For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1
        With Sheets(i)
            Set SourceCell = .Columns(7).Find(SearchTarget, LookAt:=xlWhole) 'Must Update SearchTarget# to correspond with above
            If Not SourceCell Is Nothing Then
                FirstAdr = SourceCell.Address
                Do
                    wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 2).Value = SearchTarget 'Must Update SearchTarget# to correspond with above
                    wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 3).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 6).Value
                    wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 4).Value = .Cells(3, 10).Value
                    wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 5).Value = .Cells(2, 10).Value
                    wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 6).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 2).Value
                    wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 7).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 3).Value


                    If .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 3).Value = "continued." Then
                      wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 7).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Offset(rowoffset:=-1).Row, 3).Value
                    End If




                    wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 8).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 14).Value
                    Set SourceCell = .Columns(7).FindNext(SourceCell)
                    RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
                Loop While Not SourceCell Is Nothing And SourceCell.Address <> FirstAdr
            End If
        End With
        Next i
    End If






    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub

Public Function WorksheetExists(ByVal WorksheetName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WorksheetExists = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WorksheetName).Name <> "")
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: the code above does not work as described. Im looking for suggestions on how to get the code to keep going up a row until a value other than continued is found

Comment: link to original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863663/have-search-function-need-help-editing/30870718#comment49823730_30870718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

```
    For j = 0 To SourceCell.Row - 1
        If .Cells(SourceCell.Row - j, 3).Value <> "continued." Then
            wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 7).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row - j, 3).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
```

And to add in further search terms replace the main code loop with the following code...

```
    Dim SourceCell As Range, FirstAdr As String
    Dim RowCounter As Long: RowCounter = 3

    Dim SearchTarget() As String
    SearchTarget = Split("9.1,SearchItem 2,etc...", ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(SearchTarget)
        If Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
            For j = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1
            With Sheets(j)
                Set SourceCell = .Columns(7).Find(SearchTarget(i), LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Not SourceCell Is Nothing Then
                    FirstAdr = SourceCell.Address
                    Do
                        wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 2).Value = SearchTarget(i)
                        wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 3).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 6).Value
                        wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 4).Value = .Cells(3, 10).Value
                        wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 5).Value = .Cells(2, 3).Value
                        wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 6).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 2).Value
                        For k = 0 To SourceCell.Row - 1
                            If .Cells(SourceCell.Row - k, 3).Value <> "continue." Then
                                wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 7).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row - k, 3).Value
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next k
                        wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 8).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 14).Value
                        Set SourceCell = .Columns(7).FindNext(SourceCell)
                        RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
                    Loop While Not SourceCell Is Nothing And SourceCell.Address <> FirstAdr
                End If
            End With
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
```

You'll need to edit the array for your terms though, delimiting each with a comma...
I've also tweaked the loop variables to be i,j,k in order so there's a slight difference to the first code block

```
    SearchTarget = Split("9.1,SearchItem 2,etc...", ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

To loop backwards you can use a for loop with `step - 1`.

You will need to know what the lowest row you are starting on is.  If it is just the last row in your column you can use this.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

You then loop to the highest cell that has values and if that is your first row it would be 1:

```
For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
    If .Cells(i, 1) <> "continue" Then
        ' Do things when the value doesn't equal continue here.
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: sorry I don't think I explained myself very well before this was pointed out to me so ive added some more data to the question. I tried your code but I already have the for command in use so it wont let me use it again.

Comment: @SeanBaird what is the error message you receive when you try and use another for loop?  You should be able to nest multiple for loops.

Comment: It's because you have used the object 'i' in the previous loop. Change it to 'j' or 'k' or some different identifier in nested loops